# How extract only alphanumeric characters from string? (SQL Google BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have a column called merchants containing these values:

```
Al's Coffee  
Belinda & Mark Bakery  
Noodle Shop 38
```

How can i get it to extract:

```
alscoffee  
belindamarkbakery  
noodleshop38
```

So far I've been using `replace(lower(merchants), '&', '')` for every individual character, but is there any way to avoid using so many nested replaces?

Comment: Use regex instead. You can replace all special characters in one go. For eg: Regex.Replace("your String", @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")

Comment: If you are using javascript, then try this: 'Al's Coffee Belinda & Mark Bakery Noodle Shop 38'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')

Comment: @maddy23285 running this: SELECT regex_replace("al's coffee"
, @"[^0-9a-zA-z]+","")
as t gives me this error Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "[^0-9a-zA-z]+" at [2:4]

Comment: [Bigquery standards - regexp_replace](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace)

Comment: If you are using SQL, be careful with single quotes and other SQL characters. Use PreparedStatement while sending query for processing. If you want to test directly in SQL query window, then use this : SELECT regex_replace('al''s coffee' , @'[^0-9a-zA-z]+',''). Change it according to SQL server that you are using

Comment: @maddy23285 Thanks, what worked for me in BigQuery was SELECT regexp_replace(lower(Al's Coffee), "[^0-9a-zA-z]+","") --this would return alscoffee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BigQuery, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(merchant, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
```

This is saying to replace anything that is not a character or digit with an empty string.  If you want to keep more characters, add them to the character class.

Answer (score 3):

> How extract only alphanumeric characters from string?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can also use `\W    - not word characters (≡ [^0-9A-Za-z_])` as in example below

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(merchant, r'\W', '')
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "Al's Coffee" merchant UNION ALL
  SELECT "Belinda & Mark Bakery" UNION ALL
  SELECT "Noodle Shop 38" 
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(merchant, r'\W', '') cleaned_merchant
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```
Row cleaned_merchant     
1   AlsCoffee    
2   BelindaMarkBakery    
3   NoodleShop38
```

Obviously, if you need result in lower case  - add respective function - for example

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(merchant), r'\W', '') cleaned_merchant
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you !!

SELECT 
    merchants AS Original, 
    LOWER(merchants) AS Lowercase
FROM TableName;

Lowercase column display the required results as you want !!

Comment: Need it to remove space and all special characters also, any ideas?

Comment: Use this one !
SELECT merchants AS Original, LOWER(merchants) AS Lowercase FROM TableName where removeExtraChar(`merchants`)=removeExtraChar('abc - 123')

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me in BigQuery was

```
SELECT regexp_replace(lower(Al's Coffee), "[^0-9a-zA-z]+","")
```

this would return alscoffee